# Varios produtos dentro de um pedido

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um sistema que de cadastro de vendas, e nessas vendas eu posso adicionar um produto para cada pedido, mas como eu faria para adicionar vários produtos para 1 pedido ?

Código de cadastro da venda :

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $venda = $_POST['num_venda'];
    $data = $_POST['data_venda'];
    $placa = $_POST['placa'];
    $km = $_POST['km'];
    $produtos = $_POST['produtos'];
    $servicos = $_POST['servicos'];


    include ('banco.php');


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO venda(id_venda, num_venda, data_venda, placa, km, produtos, servicos)
            values(
                NULL,
                '{$venda}',
                '{$data}',
                '{$placa}',
                '{$km}',
                '{$produtos}',
                '{$servicos}'

                            )
            ");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaproduto (id_venda, produtos) SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.produtos FROM venda  ORDER BY venda.id_venda DESC LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO vendaservico (id_venda, servicos) SELECT venda.id_venda, venda.servicos FROM venda  ORDER BY venda.id_venda DESC LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());




}

header("location:lista.php");
?>
```

Tenho 3 Tabelas , **venda** , **produtos** , **vendaprodutos** , eu pego as informaçoes das 2 primeiras tabelas e insiro na tabela **vendaprodutos** que ficaria assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está sua modelagem do banco?

Comment: Que tal um campo no form chamado quantidade?

Comment: Editei explicando um pouco sobre minhas tabelas

Comment: Como esta o relacionamento das tabelas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o foreach para incluir vários itens.
Abaixo tem um exmplo que uso.

```
$InsereProduto = "INSERT INTO exemploext_crudusuario.itensPedido (idPedido, idProduto, quantidadeDiasProduto,                               quantidadeProduto, valorProduto, valorTotalProduto, dataEntregaProduto, dataDevolucaoProduto    ) VALUES ";
       foreach ($arrJson as $registro) {
                $idProduto = $registro["idProduto"];
                $quantidadeDiasProduto = $registro["quantidadeDiasProduto"];
                $quantidadeProduto = $registro["quantidadeProduto"];
                $valorProduto = $registro["valorProduto"];
                $valorTotalProduto = $registro["valorTotalProduto"];
                $dataEntregaProduto = convertNumberMysql($registro["dataEntregaProduto"]);
                $dataDevolucaoProduto = convertNumberMysql($registro["dataDevolucaoProduto"]);
                $OrcamentoID2 = $OrcamentoID;
                $InsereProduto .= " ('{$OrcamentoID2}','{$idProduto}','{$quantidadeDiasProduto}','{$quantidadeProduto}',
                                     '{$valorProduto}','{$valorTotalProduto}','{$dataEntregaProduto}','{$dataDevolucaoProduto}'),";
            }

            $InsereProduto = substr($InsereProduto, 0, strlen($InsereProduto) - 1);
            $ExecutaInsereProduto = mysql_query($InsereProduto) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Irei tentar fazer assim , espero que de certo